# Python 2.7 Improve algorithm that checks if a dictionary key is not in a list and if so deletes that key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I was playing around with a few solutions but am looking for an optimal and clean way to do this in Python. Basically I have a dictionary called 'd', and a list 'l'. If the dictionary contains a value not in the list delete that value in the dictionary. So given:

```
d = {1 : "bob", 2 : "mary", 3 : "joe"}
l = [2,3]
```

The first key of d gets deleted.

```
d = {2 : "mary", 3 : "joe"}
l = [2,3]
```

I have a working solution but feel the use of flags is unnecessary.

```
flag = False
del_vals = list()

for key in d.iterkeys():
  for i in l:
    if key == i: flag = True
  if flag == False:
    del_vals.append(key)
  flag = False

for k in del_vals: 
  d.pop(k, None)
```

Is there a way I can write it to improve performance and make it more clean? Whether the use of generators or anything else is involved.

Comment: Make `l` a `set`, then `for key in set(d.keys()) - l: del d[key]`

Comment: There is a slight error in this, you have to make l a set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list comprehension will work starting from Python 2.7:

```
d = {k: v for k, v in d.iteritems() if k in l}
```

Use `items()` instead of `iteritems()` in Python 3:

```
d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k in l}
```

Comment: Just wondering, suppose the list had objects inside and you wanted to compare the key to one of the members of the object for each object in the list. Would this be a whole different problem or is it easily changeable in your solution? i.e. {...if k in l.attribute}

Comment: @BDillan, Can you please be more specific with an example, so that I can try and answer that question?

Comment: We just have to replace the list of objects with a list of the objects' attributes: if k in [e.attribute for e in l]

Comment: @Annapoornima Koppad Just for an example suppose you had a named tuple 'Point' pt1 = Point(1.0, 5.0) where pt1.x = 1.0 and pt2.y = 5.0. And you wanted to match the key with the x attribute of Point. (pt1.x)

Comment: @HurdyGurdy Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sets for achieving the same:

```
z={i:d[i] for i in set(d.keys()).intersection(l)}
```

or use the below

```
p={i:d[i] for i in d.keys() if i in l}
```

or do this

```
q={i:d[i] for i in set(d.keys()) & set(l)}
```

Alternatively, you could do this as well:

```
for i in set(d.keys()) - set(l):
    del(d[i])
```